# BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver`.

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<!-- When starting calculator-->    
<receiver android:name=".APP_CALCULATOR_class" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.category.APP_CALCULATOR" >
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

`APP_CALCULATOR_class.class`:

```
    package com.startcalcevent.startcalcevent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class APP_CALCULATOR_class  extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Calculator is on" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Why is this code not working when I open the calculator application?

Comment: may i know when you want to get a Broadcast Receiver message?

Answer (score 0):

I will only start when you send an Intent that is broadcasted. A App_CALCULATOR category Intent with action (ACTION_MAIN) is not broadcasted (using `sendBroadcast(Intent)`) but started as an Activity using `startActivity(Intent);`